# Rotateflip image adding to image?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an image in a picture box, and when I do this in my code:

```
    pictureBox1.Image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
```

The image has a black box on the right side of the picture box?

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to repro.  For one, the PictureBox control has no idea that the image was changed, it won't even repaint it.  At least do it like this so it knows:

```
        var img = pictureBox1.Image;
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX);
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

Comment: I actually found a solution to my problem thankyou for your response though. I actually dont need to rotate the image at all, I am just going to flip thy y values by subtracting them from the image height.